# How do i extract data from a blueprint file with js

Tags: python, node.js

I've been looking around to see if i can find a js library for extracting data from a blueprint in a pdf or png file.

[Blue print file sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRsOw.png)

I have actually not found any kind of library that could be used to solve this problem. I'll appreciate if someone out there can help out.

Comment: In order for us to better help you, what kind of information/data are you looking to extract from the image?

Answer (score 1):

For extracting text from PDF files:

pdf.js
pdfminer
PyPDF2 (Python)
For extracting images from PNG or PDF files:

OpenCV (Python)
Pillow (Python)
These libraries can extract the data from the files, but you would have to write additional code to specifically extract information from a blueprint. It may be a complex process, as blueprints can have a variety of different formats and layouts, making it challenging to extract information in a consistent and automated way.

If you are looking to extract information from blueprint files, it may be helpful to consult with a software engineer or computer vision specialist to determine the best approach.